# Can the components of a continuous injective function fail to be injective?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Can a continuous function $f = (f_1,...,f_m) : \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ be injective while each of its components $f_j : \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is not injective?

Comment: If $\boldsymbol{x,y}\in \Bbb R^n$, then $$f(\boldsymbol{x})=f(\boldsymbol{y})\iff (f_1(\boldsymbol{x}),\ldots,f_m(x))=(f_1(\boldsymbol{y}),\ldots,f_m(\boldsymbol{y})) \iff f_i(\boldsymbol{x})=f_i(\boldsymbol{y})$$ for all $1\le i\le m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, take for example $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3) : \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$, with
$$
\big(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y)\big)=(x,x^2,y).
$$
Clearly $f_2$ is not injective, while $f$ is.

Answer (score 1):

yes, consider for example $f(x) := (|x|, x-|x|)$